# How to develop a web mapping app to upload, process, and download results?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, mapscript

I would like to make a web mapping application where a user can import their own x-y-z data file, then the application applies filters that I write to it, contours the resulting data, then displays the results and exports to common GIS formats.

I have medium-level web programming skills (PHP, MySQL, etc.).

My question is this: what tools would be the best way to get my end product? Would something like MapScript work? Or do any commercial solutions come to mind?

Thanks for any suggestions anyone might have.

Comment: Sound a bit like a Web Processing Service (WPS) to me.

Comment: Geoserver can be the WPS http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/processes.html

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into several options:

- Google Fusion Tables. Great way to import spreadsheet data with coordinates (or addresses), and display on a map. Exporting to KML I believe is an option.
- MapBox. Lots of big data implementations currently in the wild. http://mapbox.com/showcase/#bigdata
- ArcGIS Explorer Online (ESRI). From a big commercial player and can become a subscription-model solution, but when you mention "common GIS formats", this could be an enticing solution. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/help/index.html#//01560000004t000000

I know this probably isn't what you're looking for since this question is tagged with Open Layers, but I figured perhaps it could give you some ideas.

Comment: This is great Mike, just what I am looking for. I shall have a look at them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [FME Server](http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-server/overview/) (Safe Software) as well.  It can upload, process, tranform, reproject, and download in to pretty much any common format.  It also has some very cool functions such as email/sms notifications and on demand feature streaming.

Good luck!